# Python matplotlib.animation [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, matplotlib, ffmpeg

I am trying to create a simple animated histogram and save it as a .mp4 using matplotlib and ffmpeg on a mac.  I have already installed ffMpeg, specified the ffmpeg path, and now I am getting a permission denied error when writing to a folder in my desktop.  I tried running as sudo and still get the same error. Help is much appreciated, thank you!

Here is the code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('.../data.csv')

df = df.dropna()
#Get list of weeks
weeks = df.ot_date.unique()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

data = df.intervals_filled[df['ot_date'].isin([weeks[0]])]
n, bins = np.histogram( data , 20)

# get the corners of the rectangles for the histogram
left = np.array(bins[:-1])
right = np.array(bins[1:])
bottom = np.zeros(len(left))
top = bottom + n
nrects = len(left)

# here comes the tricky part -- we have to set up the vertex and path
# codes arrays using moveto, lineto and closepoly

# for each rect: 1 for the MOVETO, 3 for the LINETO, 1 for the
# CLOSEPOLY; the vert for the closepoly is ignored but we still need
# it to keep the codes aligned with the vertices
nverts = nrects*(1 + 3 + 1)
verts = np.zeros((nverts, 2))
codes = np.ones(nverts, int) * path.Path.LINETO
codes[0::5] = path.Path.MOVETO
codes[4::5] = path.Path.CLOSEPOLY
verts[0::5, 0] = left
verts[0::5, 1] = bottom
verts[1::5, 0] = left
verts[1::5, 1] = top
verts[2::5, 0] = right
verts[2::5, 1] = top
verts[3::5, 0] = right
verts[3::5, 1] = bottom

barpath = path.Path(verts, codes)
patch = patches.PathPatch(
    barpath, facecolor='green', edgecolor='yellow', alpha=0.5)
ax.add_patch(patch)

ax.set_xlim(left[0], right[-1])
ax.set_ylim(bottom.min(), top.max()+40)
ax.set_xlabel('Number of intervals/week')
ax.set_ylabel('Count of CSAs')
plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path'] = '/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg'
FFwriter = animation.FFMpegWriter()

def animate(i):
    print i
    # simulate new data coming in
    data = df.intervals_filled[df['ot_date'].isin([weeks[i-1]])]
    n, bins = np.histogram(data, 20)
    yearweek = str(weeks[i-1])
    year = yearweek[0:4]
    week = yearweek[4:]
    title = 'Week %(wk)s of %(yr)s' %{'wk': week, 'yr': year}
    ax.set_title(title)
    top = bottom + n
    verts[1::5, 1] = top
    verts[2::5, 1] = top
    return [patch, ]

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, 53,interval=1000, repeat=False)
ani.save('/Users/.../Desktop/1b.mp4', writer = FFwriter)
plt.show()
```

And here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Fishman1049/Desktop/reserves_histogram_timeline/python/1b_text.py", line 109, in <module>
    ani.save('/Users/Fishman1049/Desktop/1b', writer = FFwriter)
  File "/Users/Fishman1049/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 761, in save
    with writer.saving(self._fig, filename, dpi):
  File "/Users/Fishman1049/anaconda/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "/Users/Fishman1049/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 186, in saving
    self.setup(*args)
  File "/Users/Fishman1049/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 176, in setup
    self._run()
  File "/Users/Fishman1049/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 204, in _run
    creationflags=subprocess_creation_flags)
  File "/Users/Fishman1049/anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/Users/Fishman1049/anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I am running matplotlib version 1.5.1, just installed FFmpeg today using homebrew, spyder 2.3.8, python 2.7 and OS X 10.10.5. Thank you!.

Comment: So what are the permissions for `/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg`? Is the user you are running this as allowed to run it, and to write in the destination directory?

Comment: They are read and write for my user, Fishman1049, read only for admin and everyone else. I am writing it to my desktop, which I have permission to write to.

Comment: You need execute access on the `ffmpeg`binary. Make sure it works from the command line first.

Comment: Ok, I tried:
cd /usr/local/Cellar
chmod 777 ffmpeg

and ran from the command prompt--same traceback, same error.  Thanks for your help with this!

Comment: That's not what I asked. `chmod 777` is a *terrible* idea and a **serious security issue** -- you should revert this change ASAP.

Comment: Then, does running `/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg` from the prompt work?

Comment: @tripleee--Ok, reverted. 

Yes, I can execute ffmpeg from the command line.  For example, `ffmpeg -version` returns:

`ffmpeg version 2.8.6 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
built with Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)`...